# C++ Swap the places of 2 letters

Tags: c++, string, swap

My current code

```
void swapper(char* ptr)
{
    if (*(ptr +1))
    {
        char temp = *ptr;
        *ptr = *(ptr + 1);
        *(ptr + 1) = temp;
        swapper(ptr+1 );
    }
}
int main()
{
  
    string mytext;
    printf("Type ur text: \n");
    cin >> mytext;
    char gowno[256];
    sprintf(gowno, mytext.c_str());
    swapper(gowno);

    printf("\n%s \n", gowno);

    main();
}
```

This should swap the characters of my string, like "string" it should be "tsirgn"
But it instead outputs "trings"
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `swapper(ptr + 2);`  ?

Comment: Better hope that ur text doesn't have any percent signs...

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: thanks for providing the answer

Answer (score 1):

solved, thanks Johnny Mopp

````
{
    if (*(ptr +1))
    {
        char temp = *ptr;
        *ptr = *(ptr + 1);
        *(ptr + 1) = temp;
        swapper(ptr+2 );
    }
}```
````